# How to display and process "non model" properties in create-wizard in Backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to create a new create-wizard for a custom item type and provide some "non model" fields in the wizard. These fields do not directly correspond to model attributes we are trying to create.

I would like to be able to process these values later (possibly from a prepare interceptor) where I can use these to do some lookup logic/processing and then set other attributes on the item.

I know I can technically add these "non model" properties to the actual item model itself, but I would like to avoid having unnecessary attributes that are only really needed for the wizard.

Is there any way to create a wizard as such, and be able to access these property values later (maybe in prepare interceptor for example) and process them as needed later? Without having to add these properties to the model itself?

```
<wz:step id="step1" label="create.custom.essential.label" sublabel="create.custom.essential.sublabel">
    <wz:info id="step1.intro" position="top" label="create.custom.essential.intro" />
    <wz:content id="step1.content">
        <wz:property-list root="newItem">
            <!-- actual model attributes -->
            <wz:property qualifier="code" />
            <wz:property qualifier="catalogVersion"/>

            <!-- I'd like to have other fields here, that are NON model properties -->
            <wz:property qualifier"nonModelAttribute1">
            <wz:property qualifier"nonModelAttribute2">
            ...

        </wz:property-list>
    </wz:content>
</wz:step>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SPEL
`{@bean.method(#this) != null ? @bean.method(#this).getCode() : ''}`

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it